# Missing $ inserted when printing numerical phrase

Tags: math-mode, formatting

Thanks for taking the time to reply, I did already search the forums and google and know this is a common problem but none of the suggestions I found worked.

When trying to use latex to print the phrase
"640x480 which drops to 12 FPS with a resolution of 1280×960."

I get:

```
:68 Missing $ inserted ...drops to 12 FPS with a resolution of 1280<br>
:68 Extra }, or forgotten $ ...drops to 12 FPS with a resolution of 1280<br>
:69 Missing $ inserted<br>
```

I gather this is because Latex thinks I wish to enter 'math mode' and so is placing `$` signs in for me. I've tried using `\text{}` as suggested in other posts but I get almost triple the amount of errors. I also tried enclosing the numbers like ''640x800'' to force it to be text but I get the same errors.

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Just to make this very clear: I'm writing my first academic paper and wish to be in 'text mode' not 'math mode'

Comment: At first sight, you are using `1280×960`, and the symbol between is not an `x` but `×`. You should put that (the whole second expression) between `$`. Or, may be, use `$1280 \times 960$`.

Comment: By the way, you should add a Minimal Working Example (MWE), that is, a minimal code, from `\documentclass{…}` to `\end{document}`, which we can compile and see your exact error.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Manuel, This is exactly what I want!

Comment: Mico proposed something different. You could even define a command `\res{640}{480}` which would give you the option to redefine the output later.

Comment: There is also the `texttimes` command from the `textcomp` package. Or directly type : `640 × 480` iif your keyboard driver lets you do it (for me, it was just `Shift+Alt+Num *`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you'll mostly likely be using the "times" symbol (which needs to be in mathmode to be typeset correctly) more than once, it's useful to create a macro for it called, say, `\mytimes`. (You are, of course, free to choose a snazzier name for this macro.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \ensuremath macro
\newcommand\mytimes{\ensuremath{\times}}
\begin{document}
640\mytimes480 which drops to 12 FPS with a resolution of 1280\mytimes960
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to both of you for your rapid response.
For those looking for a quick solution I tried Manuel's suggestion and it worked great.

```
$1280\times960$
```

Comment: Do you want the extra whitespace on both sides of the `\times` symbol?

Comment: It would be interesting to know how to do it without the whitespace if it's fairly straightforward. Otherwise don't worry since it doesn't really look out of place.

Comment: The extra space comes about because the `\times` macro, in math mode, is a "binary" operator and thus gets some extra space if there are math-mode items on the left and right. To suppress this space, right `1200$\times$960` instead of `$1280\times960$`